# Search records having comma seperated values that contains any element from the given list

Tags: grails, hql, hibernate-criteria

I have a domain class Schedule with a property 'days' holding comma separated values like '2,5,6,8,9'.

```
Class Schedule {
   String days
   ...
}

Schedule schedule1 = new Schedule(days :'2,5,6,8,9')
schedule1.save()

Schedule schedule2 = new Schedule(days :'1,5,9,13')
schedule2.save()
```

I need to get the list of the schedules having any day from the given list say [2,8,11].

`Output: [schedule1]`

How do I write the criteria query or HQL for the same. We can prefix & suffix the days with comma like ',2,5,6,8,9,' if that helps.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Hope you have a good reason for such denormalization - otherwise it would be better to save the list to a child table.

Otherwise, querying would be complicated. Like:

```
  def days = [2,8,11]
  // note to check for empty days
  Schedule.withCriteria {
    days.each { day ->
      or {
        like('username', "$day,%") // starts with "$day"
        like('username', "%,$day,%")
        like('username', "%,$day") // ends with "$day"
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Victor! I simplified it by changing days format in schedule as ",2,5,6,8,9," and then using only one like statement i.e   like('days', "%,$day,%")

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL there is a SET datatype and FIND_IN_SET function, but I've never used that with Grails. Some databases have support for standard SQL2003 ARRAY datatype for storing arrays in a field. It's possible to map them using hibernate usertypes (which are supported in Grails).

If you are using MySQL, FIND_IN_SET query should work with the Criteria API sqlRestriction:
http://grails.org/doc/latest/api/grails/orm/HibernateCriteriaBuilder.html#sqlRestriction(java.lang.String)
Using SET+FIND_IN_SET makes the queries a bit more efficient than like queries if you care about performance and have a real requirement to do denormalization.

Comment: Or Oracle table clustering: http://www.frontiernet.net/~rhode/cluster.html. Or what. If we really care about efficiency, we could implement Set for any DBMS with a bit field or a String-emulated bit field.

Comment: Thanks a lot Flare! This looks great I am going to try it out